# How to not have "-None-" as default in the entity reference display widget

Tags: views, entities

I spend hours to  figure this out but no result.   I want to auto-populate a
field using entity references and views.

- A field has a user entity reference
- Using filters, I made a view narrowing down the results to 1 (the result I
  want to populate the field with)
- I linked the field with the search result using "Views : ..." as a
  reference method.

The only thing that's preventing me from succeeding is that the widget always
shows 2 results instead of 1 (SEE SCREENSHOT):
- None -   (Default)
My result  (Dreece in the screenshot)

so the "-None-" is preventing me from succeeding to do the auto-populate.

Any way to (NON PROGRAMMATICALLY) ommit the "-None-" (or put it as the second
option)?
- By configuring the View
- By using View arguments?

Many thanks in advance!!![image]

Answer (score 3):

As soon as you make this field required it will have no `- None -` option anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You can use function [hook_element_info_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_element_info_alter/7.x) D7:

```
function yourmodule_element_info_alter(array &$types) {
  if (isset($types['select'])) {
    $types['select']['#process'][] = 'remove_element_na';
  }
}

function remove_element_na($element) {
  if (isset($element['#field_name']) && $element['#field_name'] == 'field_name') {
    unset($element['_none']);
  }
  return $element;
}
```